# Transparent colormap

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, color-mapping

I would like to get a density distribution plot with the alpha channel instead of the blue channel.

I found this code but it doesn't work.

```
theCM = cm.get_cmap()
theCM._init()
alphas = np.abs(np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, theCM.N))
theCM._lut[:-3,-1] = alphas
plt.imshow(img, cmap=theCM)
plt.savefig("out.svg", transparent=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug with the Colormap class of matplotlib. It exists in 0.99.x versions of matplotlib, but has been fixed as of 1.x. See the [bug fix](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/commit/b82ed5867b07f009ce910a01ba45381406621abd) for a description of how it was fixed. Upgrade to the latest version and this problem should be fixed. There is not a work around for this bug, so upgrading is the only option.