# Combining scatter plot with surface plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, surface, matplotlib-3d

How can I combine a 3D scatter plot with a 3D surface plot while keeping the surface plot transparent so that I can still see all the points?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following code plots a 3D scatter plot with a 3D surface plot:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from random import random, seed
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib as mpl

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')              # to work in 3d

x_surf=np.arange(0, 1, 0.01)                # generate a mesh
y_surf=np.arange(0, 1, 0.01)
x_surf, y_surf = np.meshgrid(x_surf, y_surf)
z_surf = np.sqrt(x_surf+y_surf)             # ex. function, which depends on x and y
ax.plot_surface(x_surf, y_surf, z_surf, cmap=cm.hot, ec='k')  # plot a 3d surface plot

n = 100
seed(0)                                     # seed let us to have a reproducible set of random numbers
x=[random() for i in range(n)]              # generate n random points
y=[random() for i in range(n)]
z=[random() for i in range(n)]
ax.scatter(x, y, z);                        # plot a 3d scatter plot

ax.set_xlabel('x label')
ax.set_ylabel('y label')
ax.set_zlabel('z label')

plt.show()
```

[image]

You can see some other examples with 3d plots [here](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html).

I've changed the colors of the surface plot from the default to a colormap `hot`, in order to distinguish the colors of the two plots - *now, it's seen that the surface plot overrides the scatter plot, independently of the order*.

To fix that issue, it should be used transparency in the colormap of the surface plot; adding the code from [Transparent colormap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8580631/7758804)

and changing the line:

```py
ax.plot_surface(x_surf, y_surf, z_surf, cmap=cm.hot)  # plot a 3d surface plot
```

to

```py
theCM = mpl.colormaps.get_cmap('bwr')
theCM._init()
alphas = np.abs(np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, theCM.N))
theCM._lut[:-3,-1] = alphas

# other code

ax.plot_surface(x_surf, y_surf, z_surf, cmap=theCM)
```

[image]

Answer (score 19):

Using the code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15231187/7758804); instead of setting transparency through the `cmap=theCM` command, it's easier to adjust the `alpha` value.

```py
ax.plot_surface(x_surf, y_surf, z_surf, cmap=cm.hot, alpha=0.2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plot points **on top of** the 3d plot, use [zorder](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html). For example, the following code will generate:

```py
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d', elev=35, azim=-125)
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0.1, zorder=1)
ax.plot(scatter_x, scatter_y, scatter_z, 'b.', markersize=10, label='top', zorder=4)
```

[image]