# statsmodels.formula.api: plotting a statistical model causes AttributeError

Tags: python, statsmodels

`statsmodels` is a Python module that provides classes and functions for the estimation of many different statistical models, as well as for conducting statistical tests, and statistical data exploration. An extensive list of result statistics are available for each estimator. The results are tested against existing statistical packages to ensure that they are correct.

I am trying to reproduce this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26431800/12278031) on my own laptop

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
from matplotlib import cm

csv = pd.read_csv('/afs/afs.sxl/python/3d/Advertising.csv', index_col=0)
model = sm.ols(formula='Sales ~ TV + Radio', data = csv)
fit = model.fit()

fit.summary()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x_surf = np.arange(0, 350, 20)                # generate a mesh
y_surf = np.arange(0, 60, 4)
x_surf, y_surf = np.meshgrid(x_surf, y_surf)

exog = pd.core.frame.DataFrame({'TV': x_surf.ravel(), 'Radio': y_surf.ravel()})
out = fit.predict(exog = exog)
ax.plot_surface(x_surf, y_surf,
                out.reshape(x_surf.shape),
                rstride=1,
                cstride=1,
                color='None',
                alpha = 0.4)

ax.scatter(csv['TV'], csv['Radio'], csv['Sales'],
           c='blue',
           marker='o',
           alpha=1)

ax.set_xlabel('TV')
ax.set_ylabel('Radio')
ax.set_zlabel('Sales')

plt.show()
```

and I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/3d/data_in_cube.py", line 24, in <module>
    out.reshape(x_surf.shape),
  File "/anaconda3/envs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5067, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape'
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `pandas.Series.reshape`.

Its [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.reshape.html) says that it is deprecated and that using it will raise an error.

You should replace `out.reshape(x_surf.shape)` with `out.values.reshape(x_surf.shape)`. It should fix your error.