# plot data as linear model in 3D with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, linear-regression

i want to plot some data like in the link below.

What can i do when i have more than "TV & Radio" in the OLS formula and i only want to plot these two with "Sales"? Because if i do like in the code below (link), it shows me an error that the others are not defined (except TV & Radio)..

thanks for help!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26434204/14208684

Here is the code of the link:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
from matplotlib import cm

csv = pd.read_csv('http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/Advertising.csv', index_col=0)
model = sm.ols(formula='Sales ~ TV + Radio', data = csv)
fit = model.fit()

fit.summary()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x_surf = np.arange(0, 350, 20)                # generate a mesh
y_surf = np.arange(0, 60, 4)
x_surf, y_surf = np.meshgrid(x_surf, y_surf)

exog = pd.core.frame.DataFrame({'TV': x_surf.ravel(), 'Radio': y_surf.ravel()})
out = fit.predict(exog = exog)
ax.plot_surface(x_surf, y_surf,
                out.reshape(x_surf.shape),
                rstride=1,
                cstride=1,
                color='None',
                alpha = 0.4)

ax.scatter(csv['TV'], csv['Radio'], csv['Sales'],
           c='blue',
           marker='o',
           alpha=1)

ax.set_xlabel('TV')
ax.set_ylabel('Radio')
ax.set_zlabel('Sales')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Please post code samples that show what you tried, what didn't work and what did

Comment: as i mentioned, with this code i can plot some data, but i want the same with one or more additional parameters in the OLS formula too. so i did the same which is ok but just with more in the formula and i get an error that those additional params are not defined. so i have no more code sample..