# 3D plot for the fitted regression surface

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I'm trying to make a 3D graph to plot the fitted regression surface. I've seen the following examples.

[Plot linear model in 3d with Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431800/plot-linear-model-in-3d-with-matplotlib)

[Combining scatter plot with surface plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15229896/combining-scatter-plot-with-surface-plot)

[Best fit surfaces for 3 dimensional data](http://inversionlabs.com/2016/03/21/best-fit-surfaces-for-3-dimensional-data.html)

However, the first one is very outdated and no longer working, and the second one is related but I'm having some troubles to generate the values for `Z`. 
All the examples I can found are either outdated or low-level simulated data examples. There might be more issues than `Z`.
Please take a look at the following code.

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

df = sns.load_dataset('mpg')
df.dropna(inplace=True)

model = smf.ols(formula='mpg ~ horsepower + acceleration', data=df)
results = model.fit()

x, y = model.exog_names[1:]

x_range = np.arange(df[x].min(), df[x].max())
y_range = np.arange(df[y].min(), df[y].max())

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x_range, y_range)
# Z = results.fittedvalues.values.reshape()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1)*3)
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha = 0.2)
```

**Update:**

I changed `Z` to the following is right

```
Z = results.params[0] + X*results.params[1] + Y*results.params[2]
```

and append

```
ax.scatter(df[x], df[y], df[model.endog_names], s=50)
ax.view_init(20, 120)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
```

I got the following plot, but I'm not sure if it's right.

[image]

If possible, I'd also like to add projections for the plotted surface.

Comment: What is the shape of `results.fittedvalues.values`? Before you do any explicit reshaping

Comment: it's 1-d, but Z has to be 2-d or something...

Comment: It does, but by shape I mean what does `results.fittedvalues.values.shape` return?

Comment: it returns (392,)

Comment: What about `df[x].values.shape` and `df[y].values.shape`

Comment: @WilliamMiller should be (392,) the example is reproducible and use a sample dataset from seaborn.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206680/discussion-between-steven-and-william-miller).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the answer you linked the critical step is the application of the model to the entire meshgrid via supplying the 'exogenous' data. In this case you can do that easily by creating a new dataframe containing the unraveled meshgrid and passing it as `exog` to [`statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.predict`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.predict.html). A demonstration of this using your example:

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

df = sns.load_dataset('mpg')
df.dropna(inplace=True)

model = smf.ols(formula='mpg ~ horsepower + acceleration', data=df)
results = model.fit()

x, y = model.exog_names[1:]

x_range = np.arange(df[x].min(), df[x].max())
y_range = np.arange(df[y].min(), df[y].max())

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x_range, y_range)

exog = pd.DataFrame({x: X.ravel(), y: Y.ravel()})
Z = results.predict(exog = exog).values.reshape(X.shape)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1)*2)
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.scatter(df[x].values, df[y].values, results.fittedvalues.values, 
           marker='.', label="Fits")
cond = df[model.endog_names].values > results.fittedvalues.values
ax.scatter(df[x][cond].values, df[y][cond].values, df[model.endog_names]
           [cond].values, label="Raw")
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha = 0.4)
ax.scatter(df[x][cond == False].values, df[y][cond == False].values,
           df[model.endog_names][cond == False].values)
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Which will give you

[image]

I have included the individual fit points in the scatter plot in addition to the datapoints to indicate this approach correctly generates the corresponding surface. I also filtered the data into two groups: those which should be plotted *in front* of the surface and those which should be plotted *behind* the surface. This is to accommodate for matplotlib's layering of artists in 3D rendering. The viewing geometry has been changed from default in an attempt to maximize the clarity of the 3D properties.

---

### Edit

Adding a projection of the regression surface onto one of the axes planes is fairly trivial - you simply plot the data with one dimension set to the axis limit, i.e.

```py
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, np.full_like(X, ax.get_zlim()[0]), alpha = 0.2)
```

Which then gives you

[image]

Comment: I'd like to add a projection for the plotted surface (like you crush it to the side). Is there any easy way to do that? If so, I could update my PO. I think it's just as [ax.contour](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/mplot3d/contour3d_3.html) but I tried and the `offset` seems weird and I couldn't found  the doc.

Comment: @steven It's pretty easy to project it onto a plane parallel with any of the axis pairs (i.e. the xy-plane, the xz-plane, or the yz-plane) - projecting onto an arbitrary plane is slightly more difficult. Which were you wanting to do?

Comment: the easy one just one the axis of each plane. xy, xz, yz... I tried but I have no idea how to specify the offset.

Comment: could you pls do this for all three axis? I'm not quite understand how this works.

Comment: @steven If you want that for a different axes plane you simply permute the command: `ax.plot_surface(np.full_like(X, ax.get_xlim()[0]), Y, Z)` will plot on the `yz` plane, `ax.plot_surface(X, np.full_like(X, ax.get_ylim()[0]), Z)` will plot on the `xz` plane.

Comment: @steven To switch whether the projection is drawn on the top or bottom (or left/right, front/back) you simply change the index of the corresponding `get_lim` method, i.e.  using `ax.plot_surface(X, np.full_like(X, ax.get_ylim()[1]), Z)` will draw on the back plane instead of the front plane.

Comment: I figured it out.so... sorry about that.

Comment: @steven No worries, let me know if you have any additional follow up questions